# Don't know what error is __init__ call error

Tags: python

Need help with this code. I have no idea why it's throwing this error when I run it -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 130, in <module>
  File "python", line 111, in encounterModule
  File "python", line 100, in CombatModule
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

---

```
#Combat/exp system test of concept

import time

print("Welcome to the Combat Concept Testing Module!")

print("What would you like your Hero to be called?")
nameHero = input(">")




class Hero:
    'Hero class'
    def __init__(self):
        #Constructor to build object
        self.name = "Placeholder" #Must Declare name after creation of object
        self.maxhitpoints = 150
        self.hitpoints = self.maxhitpoints
        self.defPower = 20
        self.AD = 30
        self.exp = 0
        self.lvl = 1
        self.threshold = 5 ** self.lvl
        self.isAlive = True
        self.maxenergy = 50
        self.energy = self.maxenergy
    def basicattack(self,target):
        #First level attack function
        self.attack = self.AD
        target.hitpoints = target.hitpoints - self.attack
        print("Target striked!")
    def heavyattack(self,target):
        if self.lvl == 2: 
            #Second level attack function
            self.attack = self.AD * 1.2
            target.hitpoints = target.hitpoints - self.attack
            print("Target heavily striked!")
        else:  
            #If level isn't high enough, attack will not occur.
            pass
    def printStats(self):
        #This module prints our hero's stats.
        print("HP: %d" % (self.maxhitpoints))
        print("DefPower: %d" % (self.defPower))
        print("Attack Damage: %d" % (self.AD))
        print("XP: %d" % (self.exp))
        print("LVL: %d" % (self.lvl))
        print("Current HP: %d" % (self.hitpoints))

class badguy1:
    'Jokes on you'
    def __init__(self):
        self.hitpoints = 80
        self.AD = 20
        self.expworth = 10
        self.isAlive = True
    def attack(self,target):
        self.attack = self.AD
        target.hitpoints = target.hitpoints - self.attack
    def printStat(self):
        print(self.hitpoints)
    def counterattack(self,target):
        target.hitpoints = target.hitpoints - self.AD




def expgain(recp,givE): #recp = recipient; givE = person donating experience     after demise
    recp.exp = recp.exp + givE.expworth
    print(recp.exp)

def lvlUp(in1):
    if in1.exp >= in1.threshold:
        in1.lvl = in1.lvl + 1 
    else:
        pass

def isAliveTest(testin):
    if testin.hitpoints > 0:
        testin.isAlive = True
    else:
        testin.isAlive = False


def CombatModule(fighter,fightee): #Fighter initiates fight
    print("What is your first strike?")

    choice = input("X for a basic strike, Y for a advanced strike")

    if choice == "X" or "x":
        fighter.basicattack(fightee)
        print("Target HP: %d" % fightee.hitpoints)
    elif choice == "Y" or "y":
        fighter.heavyattack(fightee)
        print("Target HP: %d" % fightee.hitpoints)
    else:
        print("Sorry you aren't able to do that")
    if fightee.isAlive == True:
        fightee.attack(fighter)
        print("You've been struck")
        print("Current HP: %d" % fighter.hitpoints)
    else: 
        pass


def encounterModule(attacker,attackee):
    while True:
        if attacker.isAlive == True:
            if attackee.isAlive == True:
                CombatModule(attacker,attackee)
            else:
                print("The target is dead!")
                break
        else:
            print("You have died!")
            break






print("The hero's name will be %s" % nameHero)


me = Hero()
me.name = nameHero
en = badguy1()
encounterModule(me,en)
```

yeah so I don't understand why it's throwing this error. Code runs fine after 2 sweeps through combatmodule function, then on 2nd run through, it throws that error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and consider adhering to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ (or at least consistency).

Comment: Yes, tried to reproduce on a smaller scale, sorry it's a large block of code, but this is only way I could get problem to reproduce. Here's a repl.it shell to reproduce. https://repl.it/CNRk/34

Answer (score 1):

`badguy1().attack` can refer to two things in your current class definition. The variable `self.attack` or the method `attack(self,target)`. Your code is getting confused on which `attack` to use, and is using the wrong one. Change either your method or variable name to fix this

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help. That solved the problem.